# Changing Tab using Button Click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

```
<div ng-cloak>
  <md-content>
   <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
  <md-tab label="one">
     <md-content class="md-padding">
        <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>          
             <md-button class="md-raised">Save & Next</md-button>
    </md-content>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="two"  ng-disabled="true">
    <md-content class="md-padding">
      <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>          
     <md-button class="md-raised">Save & Back </md-button>
    </md-content>
  </md-tab>      
</md-tabs>
```

I am using angular + angular material , there are two tab menu "One" and "Two"  when I clicked on  "Save & Next" button next tab should be enabled and foucs goes to next tab and reverse things should happen when i clicked on second tab "Save & Back" button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

md-selected on md-tabs shows you the current index of the tabs. 
You can change the index with ng-click on the button. 
Should be something like the following

```
<div ng-cloak>
 <md-content>
  <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="myTabIndex">
   <md-tab label="one">
    <md-content class="md-padding">
    <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>          
         <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="myTabIndex = myTabIndex+1">Save & Next</md-button>
    </md-content>
   </md-tab>
   <md-tab label="two"  ng-disabled="true">
    <md-content class="md-padding">
     <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>          
     <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="myTabIndex = myTabIndex-1">Save & Back </md-button>
    </md-content>
   </md-tab>      
</md-tabs>
```

But you should now if the next or previous tab is disabled, this method doesn't work, because you cannot switch to a tab which is disabled.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Thomas but its not working even when i enabled both tab

Comment: Which version of angular and angular material do you use?

Comment: I actually tried it now myself, myIndex++ does'nt work, so I used myIndex = myIndex + 1, now it should work

Comment: Thanks @Thomas  its worked for me . I want ask one more thing when i click on tab i want to call my data initalize function how to do it ? I tried with ng-click but its not work

Comment: What doesn't work? Wasn't the data shown? Wasn't it loaded?
May you show me your code? 
The way loading data on ng-click should be work

Comment: I got my Error  its in controller function. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

You can use function in js for changing tab.

```
<md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="changetab('n')">Save & Next</md-button>
<md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="changetab('b')">Save & Back</md-button>
```

in .js

```
$scope.changetab = function(nav){
    if(nav == 'n')
      $scope.myTabIndex = $scope.myTabIndex +1;
    else
      $scope.myTabIndex = $scope.myTabIndex -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In md-tab you can use **`md-active`**`="scopeName"`.

> **md-active** When true, sets the active tab. Note: There can only be one
>   active tab at a time.

Create a scopeArray which is contain all tab active info. And use it with scopeArray[index] in md-active.